# Kanban Board: customising number of fields displayed on the board items for individual user preference

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to have a custom views for the Kanban Board item fields that cater to individual user preferences? Perhaps there is an inbuilt VSTS functionality or an add-on which makes it possible to customise their own views of the same Board according to each of those User's requirements?

i.e. a user A is interested in having a 'Title', 'Assigned To', and 'State' fields displayed on every item on the board, but a user B wishes to see only the fields 'Parent', 'Area Path' and tags displayed, and does not wish to see the fields the user A is interested in.

Comment: Hi, how are things going? Does my answer give you any help?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have a custom views for the Kanban Board item fields
>   that cater to individual user preferences? Perhaps there is an inbuilt
>   VSTS functionality or an add-on which makes it possible to customise
>   their own views of the same Board according to each of those User's
>   requirements?

I'm afraid to say that until now, this feature does not supported by Azure Devops. You can get clearly why from the definition and configuration about Boards.

As you can see and understand, the Kanban board configured based on **team** instead of individual user.

[image]

That's why it could not be customized for individual person, this is a **public** board to show and tracking progress for team member.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, this worked. We ended up creating a new team for those users who wanted to view items differently and configured the board to show exact same items on the board, so when our team changes the state of the item, the other team sees the item moving on the board, so there is a shared flow between the teams, but those who use that other team view we created can customise how they want to see items on the board, e.g. they added swim lines and added extra fields to display on the items on the board, which would have been excess information on our team board, so now everyone is happy with the different views of same items. 
Having different teams configured in VSTS does not mean the members of those teams cannot be the on the same team organisation-wise :)